# How do I stop the "configuring Visual Studio..." message when opening Microsoft Office applications?

Tags: microsoft-office, visual-studio-2012

Ever since I installed Visual Studio 2012, when starting any Office application, I get a box that says "Please wait while Windows configures Visual Studio 2012..." and I have to sit around for about a minute.

This happens every single time I open an Office application, even though the progress bar on the window seems to complete every time.

I Googled a bit, and I found a note about disabling the Visual Studio add-ins for Office (which must have installed with Visual Studio).  I have done this.

Yet, the problem persists.

Comment: Sounds like you install some sort of Office Tools when you installed Visual Studio.  The best solution to this is to get rid of **everything** Visual Studio 2012 added and if it comes down to it figure out what additional feature causes this.

Comment: I've had this problem before. It is most likely a package installation issue. Uninstall everything, then reinstall.

Comment: Even happen with vs2010 and msoffice 2007, just have to kill the popup box before it changes the system and something else will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but likely applies to this version: [The Windows Installer dialog box may appear every time that you start Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873312).

Try removing the `Mso.dll` file in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office##` (32-bit) or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office##` (64-bit), where `##` is the Microsoft Office version number.  Then perform a repair installation of Visual Studio.  *Be sure to create a restore point before you do this.*

Answer (score 0):

Try running one of your usual Office shortcuts 'as Administrator'. You should be able to do this by holding Shift and right-clicking the shortcut, then choosing 'Run as Administrator'. You'll get the usual message and the Office application will start. Then just close it and try again the normal way. In my experience this will clean up any lingering setup issues.

Answer (score -1):

This fixed it for me:
Go to control panel's "Programs and Features", select "Microsoft Office...", and then click "Repair".  This did not require the original Office CDROM.
(my versions: win7/64, office 2003, visual studio 2013)

Answer (score -1):

Check your event log. 
I found a reference to an offline external drive.
Windows update had created a reference to mpsigstub on it.